# Junit Test imports are stopping build in gradle project

Tags: gradle, junit, import, build

My Junit tests are working fine when I'm testing them, but while building the project the build fails and reason it tells is:

```
> Task : compileJava FAILED

ge org.junit does not exist
import org.junit.Tes

ge org.junit.runner does not exist
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

age org.springframework.test.web.servlet.request does not exist
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.request.MockMvcRequestBuilders;
```

and there some others imports too which are being failed

Comment: Can you show project structure? Are you tried to clean project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out,it was failing to build because,i wrote tests using Junit4 by importing it, but i use Gradle's Junit for test then it works

Answer (score 0):

The `compileJava` task should not be compiling your unit tests. Make sure that all unit tests are under the *src/test/java* directory and that your JUnit dependencies are declared with `testImplementation`.

Comment: I figured it out,it was failing to build because,i wrote tests using Junit4 by importing it, but i use Gradle Junit for test then it works